# Can't start a new activity in Bluetoothchat example of sdk

Tags: android, bluetooth

In this Bluetoothchat example, everything is working and fine
and i would like to modify it a little bit.

I add a button in the main activity layout and its function is to start a new activity
when i run this apps, it cashes when i click this button that means i can't directly start a new activity, Why?

Here is the code

```
public void TimeInterval(View view){
        Intent intent=new Intent(this,TimeInterval.class);
        startActivity(intent);

}
```

Comment: post ur xml and manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
Intent myIntentActivity1 = new Intent(yourCurrentActivityName.this, TimeInterval.class);
startActivity(myIntentActivity1);
```

Or-

```
Intent myIntentActivity1 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), TimeInterval.class);
startActivity(myIntentActivity1);
```

And change method name to `onClick`.
Ensure that you register `TimeInterval` activity in manifest file.

If you have `android:onClick="TimeInterval"` attribute in your `button` layout xml. Then you dont need to chane method name.